# How do I disable the web part export option?

Tags: development, web-part

I have the requirement to not allow users to export my custom web part.

[image: web part export]

How do I disable/hide the Export menu option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [WebPartExportMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartexportmode.aspx) Enum. You will set this enum when adding the user control to the page. You can allow no properties to be exported.

```
<aspSample:TextDisplayWebPart 
        runat="server"   
        id="textwebpart" 
        title = "Text WebPart" 
        ExportMode="None" 
        />
```

Comment: You can also set this in the .Webpart file as a property, though obviously if someone edits the webpart, they can uncheck the checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

@Tim's answer was what I needed. I ended up using an override and I have a Web Part Property (`WPPAllowExport`) that controls whether or not to allow the export.

```
public override System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartExportMode ExportMode
{
    get
    {
        if (WPPAllowExport)
        {
            return base.ExportMode;
        }
        return System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartExportMode.None;
    }
    set
    {
        if (WPPAllowExport)
        {
            base.ExportMode = value;
        }
        else
        {
            base.ExportMode = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartExportMode.None;
        }
    }
}
```